# How do I format a double

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have:

```
double somevar = 3.45;
```

I need to format it to have the following results:

1. "`000345`" - The length should be only 6
2. "`3.45____`" - The length should be 8, left-alignment, the other part should be filled by blanks. (I use underlines instead blanks here because of some bug on this service that doesn't allow showing this string properly, but it actually doesn't matter, because fillers should be defined in the format string.)

It's so easy to do just by programming but I need to achieve it only using format string. Is it possible?

That's:

```
string format="???";
float number = 3.45;
string output = string.Format(format, number);
```

Actually only the first problem is left without answer.

Thanks!
I like you style guys, you don't like this question because you cannot answer it, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you want "3.45" formatted as "000345"?

Comment: and the 2nd one is "3.45" formatted as "3.450000"?

Comment: Brosto, right. hunter, no it should be "3.45____" where instead underlines blanks (I suppose it's bug that doesn't allow to show the proper string)

Comment: It's going to require more than a single format string to achieve your desired results. If this is not homework, what is driving the actual requirement?

Comment: Anthony, sorry I don't understand what do you mean. Is it important for you it's homework or bank's requirement? The point is I need to transform numbers in different ways to strings and I want to use only some template with string formats but the code should be universal.

Comment: People seem really combative in this question. Calm down folks.

Comment: @Seacat On the first item...if it was 0.000001 what would be displayed? More examples for the first item would be helpful.

Comment: It should be 0000001. The idea is eliminate separator like "." and if the string is too short fill the space by "0" on the left.

Answer (score 3):

```
double somevar = 3.45;

string s = string.Format("{0:000000}", (int)(somevar*100.0));
string t = string.Format("'{0,-8:0.00}'", somevar);
```

Took about 30 seconds to look at the docs on string.format.

Comment: The first is wrong because of the condition: input only number and format string, the code should not use any magic numbers and actions - only pure formatting. Moreover, what if the input number is 3.456? It should be universal.

Comment: Seacat: I answered your question as posted.  You can't change the rules after the fact.  If this is homework, next time post the whole question, and you might get better answers.